# Correllation (pandas) between date and integer? timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, time-series

Suppose my data is in the form of

```
date       | price
2017-09-09 | 13000
2017-09-08 | 20000
2017-09-07 | 15000
2017-09-06 | 13000
2017-09-05 | 15000
```

How do I find the correlation between price and time?
df.corr() ignores the date column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change date time format to numeric , then you can use `corr`

```
df.date=pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.date=pd.to_numeric(df.date)
df.corr()
Out[306]: 
           date     price
date   1.000000  0.165647
price  0.165647  1.000000
```

Comment: Thank you very much I didn't realise it's so simple!

Comment: @Zeruno yw~ happy coding